# Previewing a Template via API

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to return a page image ("preview") of a template via API before it has been saved as a envelope?

This call returns a page image for an envelope with an envelopeId: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Get a Page Image.htm

But I have not found a way to do the same for a template.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Previewing document pages of a DocuSign Template is currently not supported.  As you have found through the API call you've referenced, you can preview pages of a draft envelope once created, however you can not preview pages of a server template.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ergin, great info as always